# Internet Explorer 11 automatically adding code to js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, internet-explorer-11

The .js file contains the code:

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    slideSpeed: 50,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    autoPlay: true,
});})(jQuery);
```

It works fine on all browser but in IE 11. when I try to run it in IE11, Visual studio automatically adds `navigation:true` at first line of the function and adds `navigation:false` at the last line and then it generates an error saying "JavaScript critical error at line 78, column 20 in http://localhost:1400/Scripts/main.js\n\nSCRIPT1046: Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode". Line 78 is the `navigation:false` line

Comment: Can you create a page to reproduce the error?

Comment: Sorry? I didn't get you. @IonicăBizău

Comment: Create a JSFiddle or so to see the error... It's hard to debug something where we don't even have a test.